# How to find out how a tracking pixel got into my site

Tags: tags, adobe, google-tag-manager, pixel, tracking

I can see many tracking pixels on our website. Facebook pixel, TikTok, etc. We also have 2 tag managers implemented (Adobe Launch and GTM).
How can I find out the source of how a tracking pixel got implemented on my site. Was it added natively in the code? Was it pulled in from Adobe Launch?

is there a tool or extension that allows me to see the source and trace all the origin of tags on my site?

I looked at a number of extensions but nothing really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's hard to see the source from the pixel event. But you can trace back from the pixel js code

Take Facebook pixel as example

1. Facebook pixel is coming from the fbevent.js then you can see the initiator from devtool and it is loading from GTM contianer.
   [image]
2. But the Facebook event request can not tell the source but only the fbevent.js
   [image]

So if your 2 tag management tools is well structured. This method might help.

---

Other way :

Block the gtm.js or adobe launch code in Devtool

[image]

Then if the pixel is not firing.

It should prove the pixel is installed from the tool.